# How to print number in Sequence using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I Want to print number in sequence with thread like T1-1, T2-2, T3-3, T1-4, T2-5, T3-6

```
public class NumberGame {
    static int a=1;
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        PrintSequenceRunnable C1=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T1",a);
        PrintSequenceRunnable C2=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T2",a);
        PrintSequenceRunnable C3=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T3",a);

        Thread t1 = new Thread(C1);

        Thread t2 = new Thread(C2);

        Thread t3 = new Thread(C3);


        t1.start();

        t2.start();

        t3.start(); 

    }
}



public class PrintSequenceRunnable implements Runnable {
    String tname;
    int a;

    PrintSequenceRunnable(String tname, int a )
    {
        this.tname = tname;
        this.a = a;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        synchronized (this) {
            for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
            {
                System.out.println(tname+" "+a);
                a++;
                try {
                    this.wait(1000);
                    this.notify();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

but my output is like

> T1-1
>   T2-1
>   T3-1
>   T1-2
>   T3-2
>   T2-2
>   T3-3
>   T1-3
>   T2-3
>   T3-4
>   T1-4
>   T2-4
>   T3-5
>   T1-5
>   T2-5
>   T3-6
>   T1-6
>   T2-6
>   T1-7
>   T2-7
>   T3-7
>   T2-8
>   T3-8
>   T1-8
>   T2-9
>   T3-9
>   T1-9
>   T2-10
>   T1-10
>   T3-10

can anyone help me.

Comment: Your task is not a good candidate for a concurrent execution. Please do it sequentially if encountering order matters for you.

Comment: how to do this can you explain it

Comment: This sounds a whole lot like homework, and it is hard without more context for us to know exactly what your professor is thinking with the question. You either need to solve this without threads, or sort the items at some point.

Comment: No,This is for my practice, recently start learning multi threading

Comment: Items which have to be done in a certain order are exactly the case where multithreading is *not* a good idea, as Ravindra said. If you are trying to learn, then you want cases where there is significant work that can be done out of order.

Comment: can you help me to solve this sir

Comment: Since every Runnable object has its own copy of int a, each thread will print the whole sequence. It is doable if you use a shared lock object of integer, and update it from only that thread which is supposed to update it. As mentioned in previous comments, not a practical use case though.

Comment: Why did you want to pass `a` value to every thread? initialize  `a`  value in `PrintSequenceRunnable` let it increment itself till MAX (here 10)

Comment: If it's not an assignment given to you by someone else, then don't do it. The whole point of threads is to allow different activities in your program to happen _concurrently_ (that is, to let their states evolve _independently_ of each other.) When you need your program to do certain things in a certain order, then the best way to do it is to do all of those things in a single thread. Use multiple threads only when you can make your program simpler or faster by allowing certain things to happen in no particular order.

Comment: If you want sequence why are you using threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just *for the sake of learning*, this is how you can enforce sequential output. But note that sequential execution of the threads is not guaranteed in any way. As others have pointed out that this problem is not a good candidate for multithreading. If you want to do something sequentially, do it in one thread.

```
public class NumberGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PrintSequenceRunnable.startFrom("T1");

        new Thread(new PrintSequenceRunnable("T1", "T2")).start();
        new Thread(new PrintSequenceRunnable("T2", "T3")).start();
        new Thread(new PrintSequenceRunnable("T3", "T1")).start();
    }
}

class PrintSequenceRunnable implements Runnable {

    private final String name;
    private final String next;

    private static String moveTo;

    private static int value = 1;

    PrintSequenceRunnable(String name, String next) {
        this.name = name;
        this.next = next;
    }

    static void startFrom(String start) {
        moveTo = start;
    }

    private int uselessCounter = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        do {
            synchronized (moveTo) {
                if (name.equals(moveTo)) {
                    System.out.println(name + "-" + (value++));
                    moveTo = next;
                } else {
                    uselessCounter++;
                }
            }
        } while (value < 10);
        System.out.println("Ran " + name + " uselessly for " + uselessCounter + " times."); // remove it.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problems are:

1. The designe has problem of raise condition between the threads, you need to synchronize them.
2. At the moment of using the constructor `PrintSequenceRunnable(String tname, int a )` you are sending a copy of the primitive variable `a`, which is a static member `NumberGame`. So, each `PrintSequenceRunnable` has its own variable `a`.

My proposal is that you synchronize each thread using the methos `wait` and `notify`. I took you code and made some modifications:

**NumberGame**

```java
public class NumberGame {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException
    {       
        PrintSequenceRunnable C1=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T1");
        PrintSequenceRunnable C2=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T2");
        PrintSequenceRunnable C3=new PrintSequenceRunnable("T3");

        Thread t1 = new Thread(C1);
        Thread t2 = new Thread(C2);
        Thread t3 = new Thread(C3);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        Thread.sleep(1);//Wait 1 ms to avoid a raise condition

        PrintSequenceRunnable.activateNextItem(); //Start sequence.


        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();

        System.out.println("--END--");
    }
}
```

**PrintSequenceRunnable**

```java
import java.util.Vector;

public class PrintSequenceRunnable implements Runnable {    

    static private int a = 0;
    private static Vector<PrintSequenceRunnable> items = new Vector<PrintSequenceRunnable>();

    /**
     * Method to select the next Thread which will be activate to continue its thread.
     */
    public static synchronized void activateNextItem() {
        int index = a % items.size();
        items.get(index).activate();
    }

    private String tname;
    private Object sempahoro = new Object(); //Object to sinchrony the  thread

    public PrintSequenceRunnable(String tname)
    {
        this.tname = tname;
        items.add(this);
    }

    public void activate()
    {
        synchronized (sempahoro) {
            sempahoro.notify();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
        {

            synchronized (sempahoro) {
                try {
                    sempahoro.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            a++;
            System.out.println(tname+" "+a);            
            activateNextItem(); //Raise the next thread.
        }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

In this sample, the method `activateNextItem, from`PrintSequenceRunnable`, will decide which instance will be notified to performe its thread.

Important, i need to set a `sleep` of one second after init each thread to avoid a raise condition, i mean: To wait until all the threads were started and got all the thread in a *waiting* state.

The output:

```
T1 1
T2 2
T3 3
T1 4
T2 5
T3 6
T1 7
T2 8
T3 9
T1 10
T2 11
T3 12
T1 13
T2 14
T3 15
T1 16
T2 17
T3 18
T1 19
T2 20
T3 21
T1 22
T2 23
T3 24
T1 25
T2 26
T3 27
T1 28
T2 29
T3 30
--END--
```

Comment: This is a better approach since here thread itself decides which thread to notify next.